# Nuget.NugetPack not working with external packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to save downloaded libraries to an external package.

So I added create .nugetconfig file in the solution file. It's not in a .nuget folder as that doesn't seem to work any longer.

Everything is wrong except the Pack functionality

```
<Target Name="Pack">
 <NuGet.NuGetPack ToolPath="$(NgetToolPath)" File="$(NuspecPackage)"/> 
</Target>
```

The error msg is: "NuGet.Config is not a valid XML. Path: 'C:\BaseFolder\MySolution\NuGet.Config'.
Root element is missing."

This is weird because every other target works. And NuGet.Config should be under BaseFolder and not MySolution. Any ideas why NuGet.Pack is looking under MySolution? Unfortunately I can't specify where the config file is. NuGet.NuGetRestore and NuGet.NuGetInstall can specify config files!

It's frustrating, any help.

Edit:
I looked at the source: https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/NuGet/NuGetPack.cs

This makes no sense. Why do this?

Comment: What operation did you do in nuget.config file? Can you share with us?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT Pretty much standard nuget operations. Nothing wrong with the file. The only way I could fix it was move the NuGet.Config file to the solution folder. And set the repositoryPath to the external location. It's annoying cause I have to do it per solution but it works

Comment: Sure. That is the nuget mechanism. Set the new created `nuget.config` file under Solution folder and then it will act on all the sub projects of the solution and then it can set the nuget packages under the new defined path. It will act on the solutions of the same level directory and all solutions in the sub-level directory. You can check my answer and you do not have to use your target.

Comment: And if you want to act on all solutions on your PC, you can place the `nuget.config` file in the root directory where you created all the solutions, so that it can be applied to those solutions, or you can modify the `global nuget.config` file directly, so that you don't have to worry about scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is weird because every other target works. And NuGet.Config
>   should be under BaseFolder and not MySolution. Any ideas why
>   NuGet.Pack is looking under MySolution?

**And so far**, to do some operation on your soloution, you can create a new `Nuget.config` file under the solution folder(**It is designed by nuget mechanism**). It will apply to all projects in the solution subdirectory.

You can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) for more info about `nuget.config` file.

**Besides**, you do not have to use `NuGet.NuGetPack` to change the external packages and it is too old. You can just add these nodes in the new `Nuget.config` file to change it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>        
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\External" />  //change the path of packages of the solution
    </config>

<packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="true" />    //enable or disable package restore
        <add key="automatic" value="true" />
</packageRestore>

</configuration>
```

More info about the custom nuget configuration settings, you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file).

**Note** that when you finish these, you should close VS Instance and then restart it to enable this new file.

**In addition**, `nuget.config` under the solution folder will act on the current solution.

And if you want to act on all solutions on your PC, you can place the `nuget.config` file in the root directory where you created all the solutions, so that it can be applied to those solutions,

If you want to it works on all projects, solutions on the current user of the PC,  you should add these on **global nuget.config** file:

`C:\Users\xxx<user account>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`